# Filling a two-dimensional array correctly

Tags: c, arrays

I'm stuck in place. I cannot come up with the algorithm and will fill up the square matrix as below:

[image: https://ibb.co/JcpX6SH]

> "Gets a natural number n from the user n not more than 20. Fills in a square table as below. The numbers below the main diagonal (a21; a31; a32, etc.) are given by the user."

```html
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
 
 int tab[20][20] = { {0},{0} };
 int size = 0;
 printf("Enter the natural number n not more than 20: ");
 while (scanf_s("%d", &size) != 1 || size < 0 || size >20 || getchar() != '\n')
 {
  while (getchar() != '\n');
  printf("Error. Correct!");
 }

 for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
 {
  for (int y = 0; y < size; y++)
  {
   if (y==x)
   {
    tab[x][y]=1; // what's next?
   }
  }
 }

 for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
 {
  for (int y = 0; y < size; y++)
  {
   printf("%d ",tab[x][y]);
  }
  printf("\n");
 }

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int tab[20][20] = { {0},{0} };` - `{0}` or `{{0}}` would suffice here.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala is right int tab[20][20] = { 0 } is working perfetcly

Comment: so the question is: you want to ask numbers for *under* the diagonal? Well, what are the coordinates for elements under the diagonal - ask user to input only when the x,y is under the diagonal, using the same loop you've given above, prompting with the given coordinates of printf? what problems are you having?

Comment: I have a problem with placing numbers above the diagonal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you want.
You do not need to use if statement.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int tab[20][20]={ {0},{0} };
    int size = 6,n=0;



    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
    {
        n=0;
        for (int y = x; y < size; y++)
        {
            n++;
            tab[x][y]=n; //fill the upper part of the matrix including diagonal
        }
    }
    for (int x = 1; x < size; x++)
    {

        for (int y = 0; y < x; y++)
        {

            tab[x][y]=8; //fill the lower part of the matrix
            //or ask for user input
        }
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < size; y++)
        {
            printf("%d ",tab[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this would work for just above the main diagonal..

```
   #include <stdio.h>

    int main() {

        int tab[20][20] = { {0},{0} };
        int size = 0;
        printf("Enter the natural number n not more than 20: ");
        while (scanf("%d", &size) != 1 || size < 0 || size >20 || getchar() != '\n')
        {
            while (getchar() != '\n');
            printf("Error. Correct!");
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
        {
            printf("%d. diagonal value:", x+1);
            scanf("%d", & tab[0][x]);

        }
        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
        {

            for (int y = x; y < size; y++)
            {
                if (y==x)
                {
                    tab[x][y]=1; // what's next?
                }
                else if(x>0){
                    tab[x][y]=tab[x-1][y-1];

                }

            }
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < size; y++)
            {
                printf("%d ",tab[x][y]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

[output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EY1sl.png)